# Return string from Web API .NET Core get operation

Tags: asp.net-core, breeze

I have a get operation that I want to return a string from.  An example would be

> "000875"

When I return this string from a controller in my Web API Controller in full .NET, it formats it like this:

```
{
  "Property": "000875"
}
```

When I return the string in my converted .NET Core Controller it returns this:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "$type": "System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage, System.Net.Http",
  "Version": "1.1",
  "Content": {
    "$id": "2",
    "$type": "System.Net.Http.StringContent, System.Net.Http",
    "Headers": [
      {
        "Key": "Content-Type",
        "Value": [
          "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "StatusCode": "OK",
  "ReasonPhrase": "OK",
  "Headers": [],
  "TrailingHeaders": [],
  "RequestMessage": null,
  "IsSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

It is interesting to note that the value is not even in there!

I am running some interesting JSON Serialization to make BreezeJs work with .NET Core.  It is possible that it is the cause of this weirdness:

```
.AddNewtonsoftJson(opt =>
{
   // Let Breeze say how we serialize.  This adds in the Type and Id options the way breeze expects
   var jsonSerializerSettings = JsonSerializationFns.UpdateWithDefaults(opt.SerializerSettings);
   ......
```

I am hoping for a way to get strings through without all this mess.  Can that be done?

Comment: Can you please show us the API method code which contains the return line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I get the impression that the subject action definition returns `HttpResponseMessage`.

```
public HttpResponseMessage MyAction(....
```

`HttpRequestMessage` is no longer a first class citizen in asp.net-core framework and will be treated as a normal model and serialized.

That explains the JSON you are seeing with your controller

The syntax needs to be updated to return `IActionResult` derived responses

```
public IActionResult MyAction() {

    //...

    return Ok("000875");
}
```

`ActionResult<T>`

```
public ActionResult<string> MyAction() {

    //...
    if(somecondition)
        return NotFound();

    return "000875";
}
```

or the model itself.

```
public string MyAction() {

    //...

    return "000875";
}
```

### Reference [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types)