# Return Image as url from .net 5 web api

Tags: c#, webapi

I would like to return image url from my controller.

I have a byte array (Image).

and i don't want to return as a base 64.

I Would like to return it as

```
http://localhost:6548/image/myimage.png
```

How can i do it?

My play ground code - didn't work for me.

```
public HttpResponseMessage ImageLink()
        {
            var images = _context.Set<Image>();
            var image = images.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
            //return File(image.Data, "image/jpeg");
            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(image.Data);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  You just want to return a string?  A Google search [finds examples of that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59148739/328193).  But is your string a valid URL?  How do you determine that URL?  The code shown doesn't seem to have anything to do with that and instead is returning binary file data.  Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to accomplish and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is to convert base64 to binary stream then save it image folder inside the same application then return the URL as a string and in this case, the URL will be accessible.

the controller code will be as follow

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
        public TestController(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        }
        public IActionResult ImageLink()
        {
            byte[] file_bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("base 64 string");
            string webRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string imagePath  = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "image/myimage.png");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(imagePath, file_bytes);
            return Ok("http://localhost:6548/image/myimage.png");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Yana T is this answer your question?

Comment: string webRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
is null

Comment: I'm using web api, i don't have wwwroot